# Is there a polycount limit on normal maps?

Tags: normal-map

I can have a mesh with a trillion faces and as long as I apply it a normal map on a low poly mesh it'll run smoothly?

There has to be a limit how the details that can be shown.

Answer (score 6):

The limit will be of how many samples you choose (affect quality/accuracy) and the resolution of the normal map you bake to. Since smoothed normals are continuous, they don't have a theoretical max resolution.

The limitation will appear during the bake